# how to install oracle instantclient to connect multiple remote databases from local machine/environment in windows?

Tags: windows, local, sqlplus, remote-access, instantclient

Install Oracle (instantclient) sqlplus client in our local Windows machine with connect report database without login into linux server.

I Tested with Oracle "**instantclient_21_10**" version

Answer (score 0):

Download the Package from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

1. Download and extract the base package.
2. Download and extract the sqlplus (Tools - optional packages) in same directory.

> Open Window cmd prompt
>
> cd C:\Users\instantclient_21_10  --extracted path location.
>
> sqlplus username/password@//:/<listener_service_string_name>
>
> **Exp:** sqlplus
> myusername/password@//10.16.17.18:1521/mydbstring.hello.com

Now you are good to go to perform sqlplus task from prompt.